# AppleScript do shell script find & replace in directory

Tags: replace, find, applescript

I’ve already got a fully AppleScript find & replace script but since unix tends to be less process intensive, I’ve been trying to see if there’s a better way to script find & replace for a directory.

```
Set myFind to “string.to.find”
Set myReplace to “new.string”


Tell application “Finder” to set myPath  to the POSIX path of (target of front window as alias)

Do shell script (“echo myTarget = “ & myPath)

—// this is where I fall down 

Do shell script “grep -l “ & myFind & space & myPath & “ | xargs sed -i ‘s/“ & myFind & “/“ & myReplace &  “/g”
```

I’m not set on this code, if there’s a simpler better way to change multiple files in the target folder with the simple info of
Path
Find
Replace

Id be very happy to be put right

Thanking you In advance